# How does streams fit on a Flux app?

Tags: stream, reactjs, rxjs, reactjs-flux

I have [a webapp](https://github.com/amatiasq/term/) which prints the output of a command line program running on the sever. This output is sent using [RxJS streams](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) ([source](https://github.com/amatiasq/term/blob/devel/web/output-logic.js)).

I was trying to refactor this app with Flux architecture (from ReactJS people) which enforces the app flow in a single direction:

```
Action => Dispatcher => Stores => View-Controller
```

And I'm not sure how should I use the streams in this Flux application:

1. Should every stream event fire a new Action into the Dispatcher? Or should I listen the stream on the store and skip the dispatcher?
2. Will the constant stream input break my app because of ReactJS re-rendering on virtual DOM?
3. I've heard on a Flux video than Dispatcher ignores new actions received before the previous action is completed, does that mean than an action created by my stream may be ignored if it's firing events too often?

Comment: @Pinal I'll be glad if you tell me why do you think this is a bad question.

Comment: Multiple stores may need to update themselves based on the information from the stream. Therefore the information should pass through the dispatcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this [React-RxJS-TodoMVC GitHub Repo](https://github.com/fdecampredon/react-rxjs-todomvc) can help?

As @g00fy mentioned, fdecampredon also has a [Flux architecture implementation](https://github.com/fdecampredon/rx-flux)

Comment: Yes it does, thanks! I'll wait a few days for a more complete response and mark this as the answer.

Comment: @A.MatíasQuezada take a look at https://github.com/fdecampredon/rx-flux as this implementation is more flux-like and allows having some kind of `transaction` system in stores (or optimistic updates out of the box)

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be useful.

https://github.com/ahomu/loxe